# Android webview go back not working while rendering html

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

Hi I am developing android application in which I am trying to load web view.

`webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(targetUrl, object.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);`

inside my webview I have another link inside page. Once user click on the link it renders next page. Now problem is that from here if user click device back button it renders blank page. Not rendering any web page.

```
if (webView != null && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, another.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finishActivity();
    }
```

How to handle this thing. Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: please have look it may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/38322751/5305430

Comment: just gone through this it will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308904/link-should-be-open-in-same-web-view-in-android

Comment: debug it,u can get whether it can goback or not, and check that shoudoverride has to be return true

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    mWebView.goBack();
                } else {
                    //do any thing else.
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you try [Chrome custom tabs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdZ6U3ucLEo) ? try to use Chrome custom tab not webview

try [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdZ6U3ucLEo)